# Column names for a vector using R?

Tags: r, vector, names

```
 > coefficients
 [1] -0.052993570  0.071073199 -0.004234659 -0.005725687
```

How can I rename the columns of my vector "coefficients" in order to get?

```
> coefficients
      int           X1          X2           X3     
 -0.052993570  0.071073199 -0.004234659 -0.005725687
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would have put the quotes around "columns". As you know, a vector is  one-dimensional object.

Comment: I'm not one of the downvoters, but I imagine this is collecting those votes because it is a very simple question answered in [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html) which is part of every installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names(coefficients) <- c("int","X1","X2","X3")
```